# GUI goes blank after login screen Xubuntu 18.04 on dual-boot installation on Windows 10 machine

Tags: boot, nvidia, xubuntu, login, 18.04

I just did a fresh install of Xubuntu 18.04 on my new ASUS laptop with NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 graphics card, alongside my Windows 10 partition. I shrunk the factory C: partition by 200gb, deactivated Secure Boot, and then installed Xubuntu alongside the Windows Boot Loader from a USB key.

Everything seems to work normally...I see grub, then boot to ubuntu and I see the Xubuntu screen pop up beautifully, then the login screen.  I login successfully, then the screen goes blank (pleasing light blue color). Mouse disappears, top panel disappears, and I am forced to press the power button to get out of it.

Please help!

**Edit**: If log in to Xubuntu in text mode and type `startxfce4` I get

```
/usr/bin/startxfce4: starting X server
```

then

```
waiting for X server to begin accepting connections
..
..
..
```

It goes on this way forever.....

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem on my Desktop (nvidia graphics) and laptop (intel graphics). A workaround that seems to work for me is to change to the first console (Ctrl Alt F1) then back to the GUI (Ctrl Alt F7). On the laptop I have wiggle the mousepad to get it to respond.